After adding(or uploading) images, can't view selected images in gallery
I want to deselect images if I selected more than 4 images, here i can't go back gallery
List<XFile?> imageFiles =  await ImagePicker.platform.pickMultiImage();

 if(imageFiles.length <= 4) {
   ///successfully uploaded images
 } else{
   ///go back to gallery to deselect images until <= 4
 }

I want to go back to gallery to deselect selected images

Due to platform limitations it's not possible to show previously selected images and then deselect from it. You can just show a toast if the selected images length is > 4 and reopen the image picker window and select 4 images again.

Try once the below code :-
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
List<XFile>? _selectedImages = [];

Future<void> _pickImages() async {
try {
  final List<XFile>? pickedImages = await _picker.pickMultiImage(
    imageQuality: 50,
  );

  if (pickedImages != null && pickedImages.isNotEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedImages = pickedImages.take(4).toList();
    });
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error picking images: $e');
}


You can use library multi_image_picker_view to limit the number of images selected instead of coding the logic yourself.
